# How to access type of uploaded file in angular 4?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to get the type of file uploaded in my angular component
Here's my code 
html
`<input type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" />`
Typescript

```
fileChange(event) {                    
   console.log(event.target.files[0].type);
}
```

The above code logs file type correctly when I select any file except .doc files. When I select a doc file the type logged will be an empty string...
Please help!!!

Comment: Does the empty string occur only when using angularjs? Cannot reproduce when not using angularjs

Comment: I tried only using angular... but why this happens only with doc files? other files like pdf , zip will work fine?

Comment: Have not tried angularjs. Have you considered filing an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues) with the authors and contributors to angularjs describing what you have experienced?

Comment: No.. Iam using angular 4 here

Comment: Not familiar with the versions of angular. `"application/msword"` is set as `type` at `File` object at Chromium and Firefox when not using anguarjs. Can you create a plnkr https://plnkr.co to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Html

```
<input type="file" style="display: none;" id="fileInput" (change)="fileChange($event.target.files)">
<button (click)="selectFile()"> Select File </button>
```

TS

```
public selectedFile : File;

public selectFile() {
    document.getElementById("fileInput").click();
}

public fileChange(files: File[]) {
    if (files.length > 0) {
        this.selectedFile = files[0].type;
        console.log(this.selectedFile);
    }
}
```

For .doc it shows "application/msword".

For .docx it is application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

[Console.log Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjKbx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to file type, you get get file extension.

Try following

```
fileChange(event){ 
  console.log(event.target.files[0].name.split(".").pop());
}
```

Comment: will it be accurate to use name to get extension? what if file name is modified to have valid extension?

Comment: guess file type is calculated based on file extension, isn't it ?

Comment: will it work if I save  a text file as filename.doc?

Comment: @Mr.Gaja Of course not. What i wonder is, if file.type is able to find out that actual type of file with extension `.doc` is `txt`, is it ?